# How to start/stop a particular session connection

Tags: quickfix

My QuickFIX initiator may manage 5 sessions (targets). I can use `ReconnectInterval` to control the reconnect-try frequency.

Assume one session connection gives me a problem but I don't want to stop the other 4 connections. I also don't want the problematic session to keep on trying to connect.

Is there any way to stop and later to restart this particular session connection?

Comment: Hi. Just to be sure: you are using the C++ QuickFIX library?

Comment: yes/C++. Sounds like it's possible for Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickfix does not provide an intuitive way to disable a session.

```
void Initiator::connect()
{
  Locker l(m_mutex);

  SessionIDs disconnected = m_disconnected;
  SessionIDs::iterator i = disconnected.begin();
  for ( ; i != disconnected.end(); ++i )
  {
    Session* pSession = Session::lookupSession( *i );
    if ( pSession->isEnabled() && pSession->isSessionTime(UtcTimeStamp()) )
      doConnect( *i, m_settings.get( *i ));
  }
}
```

The code above is the loop that keeps trying to maintain all the sessions connected. Looking up to the code, there are two ways to avoid the connection of a session: 1. Disabling the session; 2. Limiting the session time range (there is no way to do it after session initialization, so it's not a valid option).

The method `pSession->isEnabled` basically returns `Session.m_state.m_enabled`, but there is no way to access the SessionState object properties, once m_state is private. The only way to set m_enabled to false and avoid the connection tries is by calling `Session.logout()`:

```
    FIX::SessionID session_id("FIX.4.2", "CLIENT1", "EXECUTOR");
    FIX::Session* mysession = initiator->getSession(session_id);
    mysession->logout();
```